# Google reviews in embedded map

Tags: google-maps

We embedded google map for a business into our website. It shows up with reviews on the top left corner, and when someone clicks on the review link via this embedded map, it does not open any reviews. I think there is a bug in google, can someone help? See example on the picture attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't understand anything from seeing the screenshots.. :-/

Comment: here is an easy way to explain,.. goto this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide     ... and click on the reviews inside any of the embedded maps and it will not work (the reviews popup keeps loading...nothing showing) is this a bug??

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, which is now fixed. Thanks for reporting it.